# Replace $ signs bounding equations within opening and closing parentheses

Tags: python, regex

I have a load of inline LaTeX-style maths strings in Python, e.g., `eq = "$E = mc^2$"` or `eq = "$F = ma$ (N)"` that I am writing out into a webpage that uses MathJAX. I therefore want to convert the opening and closing `$` symbols into the default MathJAX style of opening with `\(` and closing with `\)`, so that my two above examples become `eqmathjax = "\(E = mc^2\)` and `eqmathjax = "\(F = ma\) (N)"`. Note that a string may actually contain more than one equation, each bounded by its own pair of `$` signs.

I could easily iterate over replacements as required, e.g,:

```py
twoeqns = "$E = mc^2$ and $F = ma$"
i = 0
repl = ["\(", "\)"]
while "$" in twoeqns:
    twoeqns = twoeqns.replace("$", repl[i % 2], 1)
    i += 1
```

but I'm sure there must be a simpler one-liner way to do this, e.g., with regular expressions (I know I could have the above solution and a function and use it as a one-liner). Does anyone have that simpler method?

Comment: _grumbles about the idea that "one-liner" -- prioritizing terseness over robustness or readability -- is a desirable trait_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"... I'm sure there must be a simpler one-liner way to do this, e.g., with regular expressions ... . Does anyone have that simpler method? ..."*

You could use the *[re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?#re.sub)* method to replace the matched text.

```
\$(.+?)\$
```

```py
s = 'eq = "$E = mc^2$" or eq = "$F = ma$ (N)"'
print(re.sub(r'\$(.+?)\$', r'\(\1\)', s))
```

Output

```
eq = "\(E = mc^2\)" or eq = "\(F = ma\) (N)"
```

Answer (score 3):

```py
import re
twoeqns = "$E = mc^2$ and $F = ma$"

print(
  re.sub(
    r'[$](?P<content>[^$]+)[$]',
    (lambda match: f'({match.group("content")})'),
    twoeqns
  )
)
```

...emits:

```
(E = mc^2) and (F = ma)
```

(Take out the whitespace -- sacrificing readability -- if you *really* insist that it be "one line").